# Why does my "id" field disappear in my serializer (manytomany)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a "PriceTable" object that can contain several "PriceLine" objects with a manytomany relationship.

I use django rest framework to publish an api and I would like that when I use PUT or PATCH on PriceTable, I can also modify the content of PriceLine.
The goal is to have a unique UPDATE method to be able to modify the instances of the 2 objects.

My models:

```py
class PriceTable(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)
    client = models.ForeignKey(
        "client.Client",
        verbose_name=_('client'),
        related_name="price_table_client",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    lines = models.ManyToManyField(
        'price.PriceLine',
        verbose_name=_('lines'),
        related_name="price_table_lines",
        blank=True,
    )
    standard = models.BooleanField(_('Standard'), default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("price table")
        verbose_name_plural = _("price tables")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PriceLine(models.Model):

    price = models.FloatField(_('Price'))
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        "client.Product",
        verbose_name=_('product'),
        related_name="price_line_product",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("price line")
        verbose_name_plural = _("price line")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product.name} : {self.price} €"
```

I want to be able to send a JSON of this format to modify both the table and its lines:

```json
{
    "id": 16,
    "lines": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "price": 20.0,
            "product": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "price": 45.0,
            "product": 2
        }
    ],
    "name": "test"
}
```

For this, I try to override the update method of my serializer:

```py
class PriceTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    PriceTableSerializer
    """
    lines = PriceLineSerializerTest(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = PriceTable
        exclude = ['standard', 'client',]
        
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        lines = validated_data.get('lines')
        
        print(lines)

        # not python code
        # for target_line in lines:
        # if instance.id == target_line.id
        # instance.price = target_line.price
        # ...

        return instance
```

The 5 commented lines, are the logic I would like to implement.
I want to browse the received array of rows and if the id of this row is equal to the id of a row in my instance, I change the values of this row.

The problem is that the id disappears. When I print the `lines` variable, I get this:

```
[OrderedDict([('price', 20.0), ('product', <Product: Test import2>)])]
OrderedDict([('price', 20.0), ('product', <Product: Test import2>)])
```

What happened to the id?

Comment: It is cleaned into a `Product` object.

Comment: I don't understand. It is not the disappearance of the Product id that I have a problem with but the disappearance of the id of PriceLine object.
(field lines of the json)

Comment: Is that a field in the `PriceLineSerializerTest` serializer?

Comment: yes. `fields = ('id', 'price', 'product',)`  in `PriceLineSerializerTest`

Comment: If I put `id = serializers.IntegerField()`, it's works but it's crazy ....

Answer (score 4):

As docs says in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update:

> You will need to add an explicit id field to the instance serializer. The default implicitly-generated id field is marked as read_only. This causes it to be removed on updates. Once you declare it explicitly, it will be available in the list serializer's update method.

So you should declare `id` yourself for being able to use that:

```py
class PriceLineSerializerTest(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = PriceLine
        exclude = ['id', ...]
```